# Volume integral of of two vector fields

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

The question is to evaluate $\iiint d^{3}r\vec{\nabla}\phi\centerdot\vec{G}$ 
when $\vec{\nabla}\centerdot\vec{G} = 0$

I started with $\iiint dxdydz (\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}G_{x}+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}G_{y}+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}G_{z})$

I think that $G_{x},G_{y}$ terms can be taken out of the integral as they are constants. But I don't know how to proceed beyond this point. If any of you has come across this could you please give me an idea about how to continue?
Thanks.

Comment: I think it can be presumed that the components of $G$ are not, in fact, constants.

Comment: Also, is this supposed to be a definite integral over all of three-space? Or an indefinite one?

Comment: yeah, this a all space definite integral and the answer should be zero.

Comment: Integration by parts is your friend.

Comment: My gut reaction is take the integral over a finite ball, note that $\nabla\cdot(\phi G) = \nabla\phi\cdot G + \phi\nabla\cdot G$, and because you're given that $\nabla\cdot G=0$, that becomes
$\nabla\cdot(\phi G) = \nabla\phi\cdot G $. If you sub that in and use the divergence theorem on the ball, you get an answer as a 2D integral over the sphere with integrand $\phi G\cdot \hat n$. The only way to get zero is if $\phi$ or the radial component of $G$ vanishes at infinity...I'm not sure this is automatically true of a divergence free field.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the vector differentiation identities look vaguely similar to scalar ones. For example,
$$
     \nabla\cdot(\phi\vec{G})=\nabla\phi\cdot \vec{G}+\phi\nabla^{\cdot}\vec{G}
$$
Basically, it's the only product rule than can make sense, and it is correct. In your case, because $\nabla\cdot\vec{G}=0$, then
$$
     \nabla\cdot(\phi\vec{G})=\nabla\phi\cdot\vec{G}.
$$
So you can trade your integral of $\nabla\phi\cdot\vec{G}$ for an integral of $\nabla\cdot(\phi\vec{G})$ instead. Because you haven't said anything about the volume over which you are integrating, I'll leave it to you to decide if you can apply the divergence theorem, and how to do that.